# Only 3 finite-dimensional Lie algebra on $\mathbf R$?

Tags: lie-algebras

Please, how does one show that up to diffeomorphisms there are exactly three finite dimensional Lie algebras of vector fields  on the real line $\mathbf R$, namely $\{\partial_x\},\{\partial_x, x\partial_x\},\{\partial_x, x\partial_x, x^2 \partial_x\}$.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference at least?

Comment: Actually, I'm no longer sure I understand the question.  For any function $f(x)$, $\{f \partial_x\}$ is a $1$ dim Lie algebra.  Of course, it's isomorphic (as  Lie algebra) to $\{\partial_x\}$.  So is the claim that any finite dimensional subalgebra of the vector fields on $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to one of the three you listed?

Comment: Yes, that is the claim. So any finite dimensional Lie subalgebra of vect(R) is is diffeomorphic to one of the three.

Answer (score 3):

The result is not true.  In fact, for any natural number $N$, there is an abelian subalgebra of dimension $N$.

First, every smooth vector field is of the form $f(x)\partial_x$ for some smooh function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  We compute $[f\partial_x, g \partial_x] = (fg' - f'g)\partial_x$.  Also, I will stop writing $\partial_x$ everywhere, simply because it is redundant.

Now, suppose $f_i$ for $i=1$ to $i = N$ is a collection of smooth bump functions where $f_i$ is supported on $[i,i + 1/2]$.  This also implies that $f_i'$ is supported in $[i, i+1/2]$.

Now $[f_i, f_j] = f_i f_j' - f_i ' f_j$.  Of course, if $i = j$, then this vanishes automatically.  On the other hand, if $i\neq j$, then both $f_i f_j'$ and $f_i' f_j$ vanish identically.  This follows because because $[i,i+1/2]\cap [j,j+1/2] = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.

Thus, $[f_i,f_j] =0$ for any $i$ and $j$, so the subalgebra is abelian.

Comment: What if you replace smooth by analytic?

Comment: @Peter:  I am not sure what happens in that case, except that the every abelian subalgebra of analytic vector fields is at most 1 dimensional.  If you replace "analytic" by "polynomial", then I can prove the result is true: every finite dimensional Lie subalgebra of vector fields on $\mathbb{R}$ with polynomial coefficients is one of the three listed.

Comment: Yes, I can also prove it for polynomials. Does it extend to analytic functions as well?